# Define a filebody when provided with bytestream of a file's content

Tags: java, httpclient, multipartform-data, apache-httpcomponents

I am trying to use apache http client v4.x.

For a specific case, I have to make a multipart form request...

A multi part form request is made in java using following code--

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080" + "/servlets-examples/servlet/RequestInfoExample");

FileBody bin = new FileBody(new File(args[0]));
MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
reqEntity.addPart("bin", bin);
httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

In my case, I have the byte stream of a file body available with me,

```
byte[] bytes = value.toBinary(charset);
```

Now I want to add this file (byte stream) to the multipart entity, so that I can make a multipart post request... how do I do this?

Answer (score 4):

[Using `ByteArrayBody`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/content/ByteArrayBody.html)?

```
byte[] bytes = value.toBinary(charset);
ContentBody bin = new ByteArrayBody(bytes, "myfile.dat");
MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
reqEntity.addPart("bin", bin);
```